# E ink display reading values

Tags: display, e-ink

I want to create a project which involves reading of values of pixels on e ink display. I know there are e ink with touchscreen inputs but I was wondering whether it is possible to use only an e ink display and strong magnet ( in a pen like structure) to alter the black and white at a particular pixel and then read whether the pixel holds a black or white value. Is this even possible? I tried to search on the internet but didn't find much.

Comment: *Is this even possible?* I suggest that you research how an E ink display works, then think how that would work with your idea. You will need to be able to explain how your idea would **work**, so not explaining what it does but **how** it does that.

Comment: I read how an E ink display works..and so far I have concluded that this idea wouldn't work. But I am a beginner in electronics so I needed an experts opinion on this. Thank you so much for your help though..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not possible. E-ink displays are not based on magnetism at all. And it isn't possible to use the electrodes to determine the current state of a pixel anyway.